# SQL query to identify duplicate rows based on one record column 1 with another column 2

Tags: sql

I have a requirement to identify the duplicate rows based on two column values. The condition for identifying the duplicate records is..1st record `column 1` should be same as a 2nd record `column 2` and 1st record `column 2` should be same as a 2nd record `column 1`.

Example:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
CHN.  HYD.  600
BGLR  HYD  700
HYD.   CHN. 600
CHN.  BGLR 300
```

Here `row1` and `row3` is duplicate. I want to display only record from these two rows along with other rows.

Thanks,
SK

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no other duplicates, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where col1 <= col2
union all
select t.*
from t
where col1 > col2 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col2 and t2.col2 = t.col1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it with your sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SkSk_Table](
    [Col1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Col2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Col3] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SkSk_Table] ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3]) VALUES (N'CHN.', N'HYD.', N'600')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SkSk_Table] ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3]) VALUES (N'BGLR', N'HYD', N'700')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SkSk_Table] ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3]) VALUES (N'HYD.', N'CHN.', N'600')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SkSk_Table] ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3]) VALUES (N'CHN.', N'BGLR', N'300')
GO
```

Run this query:

```
WITH R AS(
    SELECT T1.* FROM SkSk_Table T1
    CROSS JOIN SkSk_Table T2
    WHERE T1.COL1 = T2.COL2 AND T1.COL2 = T2.COL1
)
SELECT T0.* FROM R
RIGHT JOIN SkSk_Table T0 ON R.COL1 = T0.COL1 AND R.COL2 = T0.COL2
WHERE R.COL1 IS NULL
```

The result:

[image]